# Пунктуация в деловом письме после фразы “сообщаем следующее”

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день!
Недавно в нашу организацию от нашей же канцелярии пришел образец написания письма :
   "  В ответ на Ваше поручения (обращение) №111 от 11.11.11. сообщаем. "
и уже со второго абзаца (по их форме) следует изложить, что именно мы сообщаем. Подскажите на сколько это возможно поставить в незаконченном  предложении  точку после слова СООБЩАЕМ. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Куда девалось «следующее»?

Answer (score 3):

В ответ на Ваше поручение (обращение) №111 от 11.11.11. сообщаем следующее.

Нужно поставить точку, так как слово **следующее** указывает на то, что суть будет изложена дальше, ниже, вслед за этим предложением. Текст "следующего"действительно лучше начинать с красной строки, с большой буквы.

Если же после слова **следующее** поставить двоеточие, то само разъяснение придётся начинать со строчной, что нежелательно, так как нарушается автономность сообщаемого.

А вот если закончить предложение словом **сообщаем**, то следует поставить двоеточие и изложить суть сообщения или использовать придаточное предложение с союзом ЧТО.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически - вполне можно. Но логически после слова "сообщаем" должно что-то идти содержательное. Если хочется в этом месте разорвать фразу, тем более абзац, то по негласным канцелярским правилам должно идти "(ниже)следующее", или "прилагаемое", или нижеизложенное - ну что-то такое.
Хотя для переписки не самого высокого уровня, вполне можно принять и предлагаемый вариант.

Вообще с канцелярией спорить по таким вопросам надо поменьше. Они, типа, профессионалы, а вы их щи варить учите.